# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file python flask

Tags: python, flask, command-line-interface

I am having a problem with python code. In main thread i am creating a new threading holding a flask api with:
`thread = Thread(target=app.run, kwargs={'host':'127.0.0.1', 'port':5000, 'debug':False, 'use_reloader':False})`

then in main thread i have i while loop waiting for commands from terminal with:

```
while  True:
    command = input("> ")
```

the problem is that after some commands i get:

```
File "run.py", line 44, in cli_app
command = input("> ")
```

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
although my cli is still on and i can communicate from other terminals, that client can no longer create a command.
all i found was about opening csv files, thats why i am asking.
thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create terminal commands in flask, right? so flask have a decorators to make this easy :

```
import click
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.cli.command("create-user")
@click.argument("name")
def create_user(name):
    #logic
    return
```

And to Run this command you only need to write this command in terminal `flask create-user admin`, the first arg is the function and the second is the value(dont forget to use in this, you need to set FLASK_APP), for a complete doc look this [flask doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/cli/)

The other way, if you are using multiple server in same host, create a route like commands, and to call this command access the url.

```
@app.route("/user")
def create_user():
    name= request.args.get('name')
    #logic
    return
```

And call it in url `localhost:5001/user?name=Thomas`

And create a script to run every server in background(i dont now if you are using gunicorn, so i use vallina thread pool`, and i using linux terminal)

```
nohup python server1/main.py &
nohup python server2/main.py &
nohup python server3/main.py &
nohup python server4/main.py &
nohup python server5/main.py &
```

Comment: That seems a good solution, but i am not using only one flask server. I am using 5 or 10. Does this also works?

Comment: I am using usually 5 servers at same localhost address with different ports. I just want to be able to run commands from the terminal. I am using 5 different terminal tabs, one for every server. Because app.run() is a blocking function,, that's why i runned it from a new thread, so in main thread i am keep waiting for commans

Comment: What i am asking is how i will send a command to specific server by port.
the simple thing i want is at the same terminal where server is running i just can ginve a command

Comment: the other solution, you can create routes that represents commands in your server, like "localhost:5003/create/user?name=Thomas", and make a script to  run these servers in background(i will complement my answer)

Comment: I have already created routes. As i mentinoned before my problem is that although my server is running( in a new thread that i created in main), the problem is that in my while loop at main thread  i am taking input strings (commands) with input command of python, and suddenly after many commands i am getingValueError: I/O operation on closed file